# Can not see my IP address externally

Tags: java, tomcat, ip, external, windows-server-2012

I installed Tomcat on Windows Server. Locally, if you type `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` everything is working properly.

I have also set:

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443" 
    address="0.0.0.0"
  />
```

But when I type its IP address or hostname (installation on AWS) is a bug:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

I also have an unlocked port in the firewall

Page by IP is not seen either locally or externally

Comment: Did you allow tcp port 8080 in AWS firewall settings? Also, run `netstat -an` to see if port 8080 is actually being listened on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Is the IP address a private address? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Comment: IP is public   .................

Comment: @RustyX My IP address does not exist in the list. There is only private without listening to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat after changing server.xml?

Comment: Yes, he was restarted tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `address="your_ip_address"` attribute on `Connector` tag  .

You can type your ip_address or `0.0.0.0` so that from anywhere it can accessible.

Comment: Is it a public domain ?

Comment: are u using AWS ?

Comment: cool then, Can you try to access the public IP given by AWS rather then get it from other ... ?

Comment: how did it get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS. Please check Security group for that instance,  that has to modify 8080 port  inbound rule to  allow access for globally (0.0.0.0/0)

```
<Connector 
port="8080" 
protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="8443" />
```

just enough. no need to mention address here.

now you can be browse your tomcat http://Public_IP:8080